# how to find people with the same first and last name

Tags: sql

so i had a table with 3 columns:
id \ first_name \ last_name
and i need to find how many of people share the same full name.
i had something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ACTOR 
WHERE FIRST_NAME IN (SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME 
            FROM ACTOR
            HAVING COUNT(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) >1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, Count(*) AS CNT
FROM ACTOR
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns the first- and lastname and how often they appear for all which have duplicates. If you only want to know how many that are you can use:

In SQL-Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER () AS RecordCount -- TOP 1 because the total-count is repeated for every row
FROM ACTOR
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

all others:

```
Select COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
From    
(
    SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
    FROM ACTOR
    GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) As X
```

Comment: thanks. if i want to create a function based index on it, do i do something like this:CREATE INDEX NAMES ON ACTOR(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME);
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ACTOR
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;

Comment: Seems to be a different question. Howerver, create an index on the `Group By` columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities for fixing your approach.  I think the best to learn is `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ACTOR a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ACTOR a2
              WHERE a2.FIRST_NAME = a.FIRST_NAME AND a2.LAST_NAME = a.LAST_NAME AND
                    a2.id <> a.id
             );
```

Comment: can i just ask whats the 'SELECT 1'

Comment: You also need to check if primary key of subquery is different. Otherwise you get at least one match for *every* row.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenate and group by

```
select id,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,count(*)
from 
(
select id,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME||LAST_NAME as full_name
from
actor)x
group by id,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Totals, NAME
FROM 
(SELECT FIRST_NAME+LAST_NAME  AS NAME
            FROM ACTOR)A 
            GROUP BY NAME
```